# Problem when query OData with a long table name in $select

Tags: odata

I'm getting an error when trying to post an OData request with a long table name in $select.

```
https://dns/NewOdata/odata/Table_name?$filter=LastModified ge DateTime'2020-02-28T08:00:24.78' &$select=column1,column2,column3, column4_6e76b0bf-12cb-1234-8aa9-e99974066542
```

The problem is with column "column_6e76b0bf-12cb-1234-8aa9-e99974066542".
When I remove it from the request it works fine:

```
https://dns/NewOdata/odata/Table_name?$filter=LastModified ge DateTime'2020-02-28T08:00:24.78' &$select=column1,column2,column3
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is "column4_6e76b0bf-12cb-1234-8aa9-e99974066542" really a valid property on Table_name entity set? Alternatively, share more code showing how your OData service looks like

Comment: Hey John ! Yes, this table is a valid property. I think the problem is the hyphens in the table name. Can it be ?

Comment: I cannot show you the code, I'm the QA manager. Hope you can still help. Thanks

Comment: You need to peruse the code for you OData service, identity the CLR type that is mapped to `Table_name` and also identity the property that is mapped to `column4_6e76b0bf-12cb-1234-8aa9-e99974066542` column. Use that property name in your OData request, not the column name. While in your database you're allowed to have a column with hyphens (so long as you apply square brackets), in C# you'll not be allowed to use `column4_6e76b0bf-12cb-1234-8aa9-e99974066542` as a property name. Some mapping must be in place for your case

Comment: Thanks, will let them know !